# Problems with tkz-graph under tikz 2.10

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-graph

I'm having problems with tkz-graph with tikz/pfg 2.10.  The following mwe (a modification of one taken from the tkz-graph doc.) doesn't seem to respect distances or decorate an edge.

Is this a known issue?

Many thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadows,decorations.footprints}
\usepgflibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

Node distances: default=6cm; A-C=9cm\\
Edge A-C decorated with footprints\\

      \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance   = 6 cm]
          \GraphInit[vstyle=Shade]
          \tikzset{LabelStyle/.style =   {draw,
              fill  = yellow,
              text  = red}}
          \tikzset{FootEdge/.style =
            {decorate,
              decoration={footprints, foot of=gnome},
              fill  = yellow,
              text  = red}}
          \Vertex{A}
          \EA(A){B}
          \tikzset{node distance   = 9 cm}% modifie la distance entre les nodes
          \WE(A){C}
          \Edge[style=FootEdge](A)(C)
          \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.append style = {bend left}}
          \Edge(A)(B)
          \Edge(B)(A)
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```